# PHP, MySQL Recurring Slot in Calendar using Daily, Weekly, Monthly, Yearly

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I have this problem on how can I populate the slots in database if I need to look in another table and if there is a recurring so I need to repeat that slot without even adding it, just showing the slot again in another date.

For example, I have this calendar.
[Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30iXT.jpg)
As you can see in February 14 there's **1 Time Slots**. And that slot has a recurrence **Daily** separate in another table. How can I show that time slot in another date also like February 15,16,17..29.

```
mysql_query("SELECT client_contact_slots.*, client_contacts.*, client_recurring_slots.* 
                        FROM client_contact_slots 
                        JOIN client_contacts ON client_contacts.client_contactid = client_contact_slots.client_contactid 
                        LEFT JOIN client_recurring_slots ON client_recurring_slots.clientcontactslotsid = client_contact_slots.slotid
                        WHERE client_contact_slots.client_contactid in ($ci) and client_contact_slots.date in ($dstring) 
                        ORDER BY client_contact_slots.slotstart ASC");
```

The recurrence is in table **client_recurring_slots** and with column **recurring** that will only have value **Daily, Weekly and Monthly, Yearly**.

Can somebody help me?
Thank you.